# search keyup event with debounce functionality is not working on mobile app

Tags: javascript

Searching using keyUp event with debounce functionality in javascript is not working on mobile app.

but it's properly working on website.

what can i do to work my search functionality in mobile app.

Comment: addEventListener("touchend", (event) => {});